# HTML:For loop in vbScript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I`m trying to add three labels and three controls in a row.

### Code

```
<html>
 <body>
    <table class="shadedTable4" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr border="1">
<td>
<input type =checkbox name="ChildCheck" id="ChildCheck" value="1"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Apply  to all fields</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><input class="FullTextArea" id="applyfieldscontrol" name="applyfieldscontrol" style="overflow-x:hidden;height:44px;" value="" rows="5" cols="10" >                    
</input>
</td>
</tr>
            <tr>
                <% 
                dim CountFlg
                CountFlg = 0
                for i=0 to XmlNodes.length-1
                    if CountFlg <= 2 then %>
                        <td class="style3" >
                            <span class="style4">
                                <b><%=XmlNodes.item(i).getAttribute("Name")%></b>
                            </span>&nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <TD>
                            <input class="FullTextArea" name="<% i % >" id="<% i %>" style="height:35px;overflow:auto;padding-left:80px;" rows="5"cols="10"> </input>
                        </TD>
                        <% CountFlg=CountFlg+1
                    end if
                next%>
            </tr>       
     </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Here XmlNodes will have more than 3 xml nodes.

So what i have to do is,display three in a row,and after three again next row will have three more labels+controls(TextArea) and so on.

Is there a better logic to implement this?

Suggest me some some answers please.

Comment: an advice: your title is misleading because this code is in vbScript not in javascript, and tag according to the language technologies implied in your question not only the main technology (Claasic-asp). Indent your code for better readibility. and Btw </body> comes before </html>

Comment: @Rafael:Sorry for the mistake.i edited it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code your statement "if CountFlg <= 2 then" is causing anything after the third node not to be displayed. The following code will create a new table row after each third node. It works by simply seeing if "i" is a multiple of 3.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <% For i = 0 To XmlNodes.Length - 1 
                    if (i / 3) = Int(i / 3) Then %> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <% End If %>
                <td class="style3" >
                    <span class="style4">
                        <b><%= XmlNodes.item(i).getAttribute("Name") %></b>
                    </span>&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="FullTextArea" style="height:35px;overflow:auto;padding-left:80px;" rows="5"cols="10" />
                </td>
                <% Next %>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

NB. You were also missing TABLE tags from your example and as someone else had mentioned, you closed HTML before your BODY tag.

Comment: :Thanks for the reply and answer.It worked fine.I just needed a logic.And this one worked fine.

Comment: :But I got a problem here.Not all the textarea have same width.How to make this happen?

Comment: @user1495475 -- change `<input class="FullTextArea" style="height:35px;overflow:auto;padding-left:80px;" rows="5"cols="10" />` to `<textarea class="FullTextArea" style="height:35px;overflow:auto;padding-left:80px;" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>`

Comment: @John: <TD><input class="FullTextArea" name="<% i % >" id="<% i %>" style="height:35px;overflow:auto;padding-left:80px;" rows="5"cols="10"> </input></TD> Here i`m naming that td dynamically.Giving id also.It`s not working.

Comment: @user1495475 -- replace `name="<% i % >" id="<% i %>"` with `name="<%=i % >" id="<%=i %>"` and it should work; you weren't echoing the variable out.